# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio scaling issue on 4k display

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does anyone know how to fix the SQL Server Management Studio scaling problem on 4k displays?

I am having some weird scaling happening:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to SSMS 2016 I used this and it worked ok.

**[SSMS in High-DPI Displays: How to Stop the Madness](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/10/14/ssms-in-high-dpi-displays-how-to-stop-the-madness/)**

Now I just use SSMS 2016 which has built in support.

Comment: I've followed this already and it doesn't work for me, I am using two displays both 4k @SQLChao

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban It worked for me but it wasn't great. I really would recommend giving SSMS 2016 a shot

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban Please don't make edits that change the meaning of an answer, such as adding whether or not the answer worked for you.